# How to extract the value of a slider bar chosen by the user in a shiny app, in order to use it in a function?

Tags: r, shiny

So I have this reproducible shiny app with a slider bar:

```
library(bold)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(stringr)
library(readr)

grades2<-function(groups){
  taxon<-bold_seqspec(taxon=groups, format = "tsv")
  taxon2<-taxon[taxon$species_name!=""|is.na(taxon$species_name),]
  taxon2<-taxon2[!(taxon2$bin_uri == "" | is.na(taxon2$bin_uri)), ]
  taxon2$base_number=str_count(taxon2$nucleotides, pattern="[A-Z]")
  taxon2<-taxon2[(taxon2$base_number>input$seqsize),]
  assign('taxon',taxon,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}


ui <- navbarPage(title=tags$h3("APP"),tabPanel(column(12,align="center",tags$h4("Download"),tags$br(),
                                                      sliderInput("seqsize", "Mininum number of base pairs for sequences in reference library:",min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500),textOutput("SliderText"),
                                 textInputAddon(inputId="taxa2",addon=icon("search"),width="500px",label=tags$h5(tags$strong("Enter the name of the taxonomic group or groups separated by commas, without spaces:")),placeholder="Example: Carnivora,Ursidae,Artiodactyla,Soricomorpha"),
                                 downloadButton("downloadData_2","Download"))))

server <- function(input, output){
  taxaInput_2 <- reactive({grades2(unlist(strsplit(input$taxa2, ",")))})
  output$downloadData_2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(to_upper_camel_case(input$taxa2,sep_out=","), ".tsv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      shiny::withProgress(
        value=10,
        {
          shiny::incProgress(10/10)
          write_tsv(taxaInput_2(), file)
        }
      )
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I have creted a slide bar input, but I don't know how to extract the value that the user choses, so to use it in my function named "grades2". What I want is for the variable "input$seqsize" in this line of code to be the value chosen by the user in the slider bar:

```
taxon2<-taxon2[(taxon2$base_number>seqsize),]
```

The problem is I'm gettin the following error:

```
Warning: Error in [.data.frame: object 'input' not found
```

Thank you in advance for any answers

Comment: I suggest adding an argument to your function for it, and include it from the reactive part. That is, `grades2<-function(groups, size) { ... ; taxon2<-taxon2[(taxon2$base_number>size),]; ... }`. Then call it as `reactive({grades2(unlist(strsplit(input$taxa2, ",")),input$seqsize)})`. (Sorry, code in comments stinks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you rewrite your function to remove any notion of reactivity: keep it naive to the fact that it's operating within `shiny`.

```r
grades2<-function(groups, size){
  taxon<-bold_seqspec(taxon=groups, format = "tsv")
  taxon2<-taxon[taxon$species_name!=""|is.na(taxon$species_name),]
  taxon2<-taxon2[!(taxon2$bin_uri == "" | is.na(taxon2$bin_uri)), ]
  taxon2$base_number=str_count(taxon2$nucleotides, pattern="[A-Z]")
  taxon2<-taxon2[(taxon2$base_number>size),]
  assign('taxon',taxon,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

and

```r
  taxaInput_2 <- reactive({grades2(unlist(strsplit(input$taxa2, ",")), input$seqsize)})
```